# how to resolvetypes with graphQl and sequelize

Tags: javascript, graphql, sequelize.js

hi i have an interface type that im trying to query but does not work despite following examples. i am using sequelize to handle my backend database mysql. may i have some help on this? my suspicion is that the "__resolveType" needs to be done within my const Query but i am not sure how to execute it. any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

resolvers.js

```
    const Query = {

        ActionInterface: async() => {
         try{
        const ai = await ActionInterface_Table.findAll();
        return ai;
         }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        }

     },

        Actions: async () =>{
            try{
                const aa = await Action_Table.findAll();
                return aa;
            }catch(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
         }
     }


    const { where } = require('sequelize');
    const { Authors,Books, sequelize } = require('../models');
    const initModels = require("../models/init-models");
    const models = initModels(sequelize);


    const ActionInterface={
        __resolveType:(obj, context, info)=>
        (
           if(obj.abbrv){
             return 'Action';
           }
#this is how i retrieve other tables within the action type
const Action = {
    actionKpis:async () => await SimpleKpi.findAll(),
    assignee:async () => await Cyber_Strategy_Team.findAll(),
    forum:async ()=> await Forum_Table.findAll(),
    pivotTab:async ()=> await PivotTab_Table.findAll(),
}

 
    module.exports = { Query , ActionInterface, Action }
```

typedefs.graphql

```
interface ActionInterface {
    actionKpis:[simpleKpis],
    actionSortKey:Int
    assignee:[Team]
    complete:Boolean
    createdAt:String
    forum:[Forum]
    id:ID
    milestones:[Milestones]
    origin:String
}

type Action implements ActionInterface {
  action:String
  topic:String
  actionKpis:[simpleKpis],
  actionSortKey:Int
  assignee:[Team]
  complete:Boolean
  createdAt:String
  forum:[Forum]
  id:ID
  milestones:[Milestones]
  origin:String
}

type Query {
  ActionInterface:[ActionInterface]
}
```

within my graphql playground this is my query

```
{ActionInterface {
       ... on Action {
    action
      }
  }
}
```

it returns

```
{
  "errors": {
    "message": "Abstract type \"ActionInterface\" must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field \"Query.ActionInterface\". Either the \"ActionInterface\" type should provide a \"resolveType\" function or each possible type should provide an \"isTypeOf\" function."
      }
}
```

Comment: How does it not work? What query are you running? What error message do you get?

Comment: Btw, `BookTitle` should be camelCase, your type names should be singular, and an `Author` should not implement a `Book` interface.

Comment: it just returns "null"

Comment: You haven't shown any code of a resolver that returns something, but my guess would be that's where the issue is and not the `__resolveType`.

Comment: i edited my code snippet @Bergi

Comment: `Author.book` is defined in your schema as returning a single Book, but appears to return a list (an array) - the `findAll` would be more appropriate for `Query.books`. The same problem with a list instead of an object for `Book.author`. As I wrote previously, your schema is really messed up.

Comment: updated my schema with what im really trying to do. create a resolvetype for an interface and then query that interface @Bergi

Comment: @Bergi Example i've been following. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/unions-interfaces/

Comment: Ah, that's looking very different! The `Query.ActionInterface` field still should be lowercase though. Please also add the code of its resolver (i.e. then one that returns the list of actions), the query you are running, and a log output of the value that the `Query.actionInterface` resolver actually returns.  Do the objects have `.abbrv` properties? And please post the whole code of the `__resolveType` function, currently that code is a syntax error.

Comment: @Bergi i made the necessary edits